# Laravel: Customize, customize, customize?

Tags: php, laravel, yii

I am a switcher, from Yii1 to Laravel 5 - 5.1 to be precise - and I am having a good slew of questions.

Within my app ("BIRD3"), I have a NodeJS server that uses the hprose RPC system to talk to a PHP server to query it run a request and return the result (the PHP server is multi-process and spawns a sub-process per request). This proposes a few difficulties; headers, cookies, sessions.

In my Yii1 based app, I used an in-development branch of the `runkit` extension. But, as you can tell, this is super hacky, not clean, and dependency-wise, not a smart idea. But it worked, for the most part. Here is a snippet from that very bit of code I did:

```
<?php
// Header.
runkit_function_redefine("headers_sent", '', 'return false;');
runkit_function_redefine(
    "header", '$to,$replace=false,$status=200',
    'return HttpResponse::header($to);'
);
// We have a custom handler.
runkit_function_redefine(
    "setcookie",
    '$name,$value,$expire=0,$path="/",$domain=null,$secure=false,$httponly=false',
    'return HttpResponse::setcookie($name,$value,$expire,$domain,$secure,$httponly);'
);
// Because...
runkit_function_redefine(
    "session_regenerate_id",
    '$deleteOld=false',
    'return bird3_session_regenerate_id($deleteOld);'
);
```

Now, why did I need this? Simple: Yii does not have a direct way to override Session/Header/Cookie management without doing a good load of wiring of the internals. Overriding internal dependencies with extended, derived classes is not very easy and bulks up the config file a lot.

So my question number one is:
Does Laravel give me the possibility to extend a few classes, override methods that do Session and Header and Cookie management and enhance it to use my custom functions instead?

Next on, I'd like to know something else that is very important; modularization. In Yii, all you have to do is run these commands and you are 2/3 done of creating a module:

```
$ mkdir -p protected/modules/myModule
$ echo "<?php class MyModule extends CWebModule {}" > protected/modules/myModule/MyModuleModule.php
```

... or something like that. But, it is as simple as that. Just add an entry into the configuration file, and you are good to go.

But how do I integrate the idea of modules into a Laravel app? I saw a few projects on github that suggest themselves to "implement modularization" into Laravel. It seems that Laravel 5 does not support modules. This is...kinda strange. An appearently "ultimative" PHP framework not being able to do modules does seem off.

So I would like to know:
What steps, and how many, do I have to do to:
- Implement modularization
- Use modularization
- Automatically place routes to the modules

Next on is error handling. How does Laravel handle errors, or exceptions? Do I just define a special route within the router that gets executed?

I know, these are big, and long questions in one single thread. I hope this is fine for SO. I just have 2 weeks in which I am very free to code and I would like to perform the switch very fast. I will likely run Yii1 alongside L5 for a while untill all the code is translated over. Mainly, my models will be the last ones that I will translate. Because, in fact, Yii1 is very nice and I enjoyed using it. But seeing that it is going to be deprecated is a bummer. So, better transist to Laravel now than never is what I would assume.

Thanks for your help in advance! :)

Comment: Too many questions. You should really refactor this into multiple questions.

Comment: Please do that, those are interesting questions.

Comment: @tacone What is the way to "close" a question? I'll do that, then.

Comment: You don't have to close this one, just use the **edit** option below the tags, and keep only one of the topics, and for the rest create different questions. But if really want to **delete** it, the option is in the same place as edit.

Comment: Also, some of the questions you posed, such as [extensibility](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/extending) and [error handling](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/errors), can be answered with a simple google search, as they are general topics. And if you're intent on learning Laravel, I **strongly** suggest you go over the whole [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1). It won't take that long and you'll get a very good sense of what Laravel can do and how to do it.

Comment: I suggest to do edit the question as @bogdan said and open new ones. I don't agree with the demand to read more documentation, the questions are very good and deserve to get an answer on this website.

Comment: @tacone I wasn't saying that those questions should not be asked, just that there is a good way of doing things. Generally you want to do some research (also the first thing underlined by the [SO Help Center](http://bit.ly/1K94Z9d)), then ask the proper questions if there are problems in understanding. The question "_what have you tried_?" is asked way too often in StackOverflow comments, so suggesting doing some research is not inappropriate at all. If you feel like those questions need answers on SO, then feel free to ask (and if you want, answer them yourself) because it's perfectly ok.

Comment: @tacone,Bogdan I am separating this big question into smaller ones now. Thanks for your advices. I did look into the documentation and learned some stuff about Laravel itself, but not much of these questions was answered to me, so they still stand. Again, thanks for your comments. :)